# Apache better http compression

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I generated a 500 MB empty file on Windows 10 using CMD `fsutil file createnew <filename> <length>` and I uploaded it to two servers:

1. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS dedicated server with PHP 7.1.3-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 and Apache/2.4.25. This is brand-new, not configured server.
2. Some random shared hosting.

When I try to download it from the dedicated server it takes a while (some 2 minutes) but when I try to download it from the shared hosting it happens instantly in 1 second.

So, I'm guessing that they enabled some kind of compression that detected that the file consists of all zeros ("00000000...") and they could send it in one second.

How can I enable this kind of compression in my Apache? `mod_deflate` is enabled by default on Ubuntu so this is not that thing I believe.

Here's clarification:

1. In both cases the file size in my "Downloads" folder is 500 MB. Some people are suggesting that I downloaded a 0 MB file in 1 second: No.
2. Both servers are connected to 1 Gbps connection and I'm connected to only ~40 mbit/s so of course there would be no possibility of me downloading 500 MB in 1 second.
3. The download time from shared hosting is 1 second (maybe 2). It happens instantly.
4. When I upload or download this 500 MB file via FTP then in both cases it takes a long time (2+ min). Only via HTTP the difference is 1 second vs 2 minutes.

I'm sure that more shared hostings have this behavior so if someone has access to Bluehost, Godaddy etc. then they can try this and I'm sure they will also get a 1 seconds download on a 500 MB empty file on some shared and well-configured hostings.

Comment: What network is each connected to? That is likely your bottleneck

Comment: What size is the file you can download in 1 second? I would expect you are getting a 0 byte size file. The issue may be with how the file is uploaded to both server. It may be related to how the multipart upload is being handled by the different OS's and has nothing to do with the HTTP delivery. Is the file 0 bytes or 500MB?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.